# How do I remove Windows user shell folders in Windows 11?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, onedrive

OneDrive is a cancer on my computer that I just can't get rid of.
I uninstalled OneDrive, but Windows still insists on automatically creating these folders after I delete them.
After some Googling I figured out how to find them in regedit. Not sure what to do from here.

Address: Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
[image: regedit user shell folders]

Comment: OneDrive has nothing to do with the Shell Folders.

Comment: "OneDrive is a cancer" .. agreed but this is not how to go about fixing it.

Comment: @harrymc The OneDrive folder is automatically created every time my computer restarts even though OneDrive is uninstalled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list shows **all** Windows built-in shell folders. Do **not** get rid of them, since Windows requires some. You can, however, **hide** unwanted folders, though. Save the following as a .reg file to hide OneDrive:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}]
"System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}]
"System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree"=dword:00000000
```

After executing it, OneDrive will no longer show in Explorer.

You can also hide [Quick Access](https://softwarekeep.com/help-center/how-to-remove-quick-access-in-windows-10).